# Interpret string with batch-style environment variables in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, environment-variables, appv

I have a string including environment variables in batch-style notation (`%programdata%\App-V`) that I need to evaluate in Powershell. Can the `%ENV%` notation be easily evaluated in Powershell?
I am aware that the usual notation for environment variables in Powershell would be `$env:ProgramData`, but the string is returned to me from another command that I cannot change.

Background information:
A Powershell Cmdlet (`(Get-AppvClientConfiguration -Name PackageInstallationRoot).Value`) oddly returns a string with batch-style environment variables (`%programdata%\App-V`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `[environment]` type accelerator for that:

```
[environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables('%programdata%\App-V')
```

returns `C:\ProgramData\App-V`